# After installing EntityFramework5.0.0 on .NET4.5 Error: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception at Runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I am again raising this question because previous question are unsolved.

I have installed EntityFramework 5.0.0 on .Net 4.5 (MVC4), by using a linq query fetching the result of a employee based on id.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    EmployeeContext empctxt = new EmployeeContext();
    Employee employee = empctxt.Employees.Single(emp => emp.employeeid == id);
    return View(employee);
}
```

Expected to display record of the entered id employee, but giving runtime error as `The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.` on the line `EmployeeContext empctxt = new EmployeeContext();`

**Web.Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <configSections>

  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="EmployeeContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="SERVER=DESKTOP-DO6F13P;DATABASE=mvctrialdbase;uid=sa;pwd=sa@123;"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The problem is not in fact in the posted code, but that the Entity Framework is unable to parse the configuration in application's config file (`Web.config`). Please ensure the configuration is valid, especially the EF provider and connection string. You can also update the question with the contents of your config file (without sensitive data)

Comment: @MartinZikmund Kindly check the above question, I have updated the question with Web.Config code.

Comment: Please run the application again and when the exception is thrown, check the `InnerException` and what it says. It should provide more details. Please update the question with this info as well

Comment: sir how to check InnerException in MVC4? Actually I am new to MVC therefore don't know how to check it.

Comment: Wen the exception is thrown, you should see a "popup" with the exception, where should be a link to "Exception details", if you click on that, you should see a kind of property browser, where should be property called "InnerException" which should contain yet another exception with some info. You can even post screenshots and I can help you navigate there (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-00-05/3582.UncaughtExceptionImage.png)

Comment: kindly click on ErrorScreenshot link to view error image 
[Error Screenshot](https://photos.google.com/u/1/photo/AF1QipPUBSMjD6dF2UGgILkZAW755lS_zbHKE6uRshZ9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in **web.config**. While adding `Entity Framework` the `<provider></provider>` tag is being added automatically to the **web.config** file.

Code Added automatically:

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Therefore `<provider></provider>` tags need to be **delete** or has to **comment**.